# How to align image above unordered list items

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have an unordered list item element with some list items and links. Above each link I would like to show an image. I would like the text to be horizontally aligned below the relevant image.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Bag</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a:before {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/50x50') no-repeat center;
  content: '';
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `text-align:center` to the `li` and a left/right margin of `auto` for the pseudo element and then you can go one step further and set a `width` for the `li` so that they're all the same width regardless of the length of the text.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width:75px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

li a {
  display:block;
}
  li a:before {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/50x50') no-repeat center;
    content: '';
    margin:0 auto 5px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Bag</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the margin between the link and image clickable too?

Comment: Yep, just use `display:block;` on the anchor, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using flexbox.

You can make the `a` element a flex container, and center the content horizontally.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 4em;
}

li a:before {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/50x50') no-repeat center;
  content: '';
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Bag</a></li>
</ul>
```